# MS Access 2013: Statistics: How to encode/recode text values

Tags: ms-access

I tried to google my question, but I only get results about encryption.

I've a big database which contains data to be used in statistics. I've many text fields which can have between 1 and 15 different values, which is encoded in numbers. (like 1=this 2=that 3=other) Is it possible in an easy way to switch between text-value and int-value? The only way I found is doing it per hundreds of IIf in a query...
(Most statistical applications, like SPSS, provide this functionality.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- One way is to use Array ... like Code(15) with Code(1) = "this", Code(2) = "that", etc...
- Another way, create a table with 2 fields: 1.. this, 2... that, etc.

Comment: Hm I alsou thought of a reference table, but is it possible to connect this in an easy way (I have about 50 fields...)

Comment: Thanks, found out how to connect the reference table!